# Updating data from DE to other DE in Exact Target?

Tags: marketing-cloud

How can I update data onto one data extension of other data extension and save the data in the form of json?

Comment: Till now i worked on updating data using amp script. Now i have to update data onto one data extension of other data extension i don't know how to do this can you give any way to go for acheive this

Comment: Please make good faith attempt in your question -- even if it's work-in-process code. Otherwise you're unlikely to get much help.

Comment: Set Primary Keys and data in Data Extensions can be updated with Query using a Select Statement.

Answer (score -1):

Please Use This Code One DE To Another DE Move The Data And Copy The Data.this code. Don't use Primery ky Fields.

```
   <script runat=server>
   Platform.Load("Core","1");
   var birthdayDE = DataExtension.Init("DE11");
   var newData = DataExtension.Init("DE33")
   var data = birthdayDE.Rows.Retrieve();
   Write(Stringify(data.length));
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var sub = data[i];
   newData.Rows.Add({Email:sub.Email,Lastname:sub.Lastname});

  }
 </script>
```